# Rotate 3D Model in XNA

Tags: c#, matrix, xna, rotation

I am new to XNA, and I am creating a simple game. Sorry that this is probably really simple, but I can't find any help on it. There is a ship in the game that I made with Blender, and I want to be able to control the ship by being able to rotate the ship's X, Y and Z axises. Here is the code I have:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
  RotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.PiOver2) * Matrix.CreateRotationY    (rotationY) * Matrix.CreateRotationX(rotationX) * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(rotationZ);

        Matrix shipTransformMatrix = RotationMatrix * Matrix.CreateTranslation(ship.Position);

                        DrawModel(ship.Model, shipTransformMatrix, ship.Transforms);
        // TODO: Add your drawing code here


        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }

    public  void DrawModel(Model model, Matrix modelTransform, Matrix[] absoluteBoneTransforms)
    {
        //Draw the model, a model can have multiple meshes, so loop
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            //This is where the mesh orientation is set
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {

                effect.World = absoluteBoneTransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * modelTransform;
                effect.Projection = projectionMatrix;
                effect.View = viewMatrix;

            }

            //Draw the mesh, will use the effects set above.
            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }
```

This will rotate the ship, but not along the ship's axis's. If I rotate the Y axis (by changing the value of rotationY), the ship will rotate along its Y axis. But if I rotate the X or Z axis, the ship rotates according according to the world's X and Z axises, not its own. How do I make it so the ship rotates on its own axises? Do I need to do something different with the matrices?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using CreateRotationX, CreateRotationY, & CreateRotationZ all apply rotations around the world or global axes. Meaning it causes your object to rotate only around the world/global axes, not your object's local axes.

Using CreateFromAxisAngle allows you to input whatever rotation axis you want, including the ship's own local axes.

A shift in your overall rotation paradigm will be needed, however, since a rotation around an arbitrary axis like the ship's Up, for instance, can cause a change to any of the 3 angle values at once. Keeping track of all that is unnecessarily difficult. There is an easier way:

Simply store a rotation in matrix (or quaternion) form instead of the 3 angles.

Comment: Thanks. How do I define the my ship's rotation axis in the CreateFromAxisAngle? I tried, and all it did was morph my ship. How do I store a rotation in a matrix? That's what I have been trying to do.

Comment: It just so happens I wrote a blog post about it.  http://stevehazen.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/matrix-basics-how-to-step-away-from-storing-an-orientation-as-3-angles/

Comment: Thanks. I had found the link you put up right before you put it up. lol. I read it and was able to fix the problem. Thank you! It was really clear and really helpful

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Giving some credit here to Steve below (great answer mate, been a while since I did alot of 3D math).

This tutorial here will show you how to setup what Steve suggested!

http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series1/Rotation_-_translation.php

Original Post:

I believe you have to create an effect.Rotation in your BasicEffect loop.

All of this is covered in the basic tutorials over at MSDN I believe. Your code even looks like it came from there.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203897(v=xnagamestudio.31)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203897%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29)

If not, check out this link, Reimer covers everything in 3D worth knowing to start:

http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/series1.php

Comment: Thanks. I tried creating an effect.Rotation in my BasicEffect loop, but there was no Rotation property for the effect. My problen isn't rotating the model, I can do that, it is having the models axises rotate with the model. When I do `RotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.PiOver2) * Matrix.CreateRotationY    (rotationY) * Matrix.CreateRotationX(rotationX) * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(rotationZ);`, whichever axis I create a rotation for first rotates with the ship, but the two after it don't.Is there a certian order I have to multiple the matrices in to have them rotate w/the model?

Comment: The order doesn't really matter (as far as I've ever noticed).

But I do see your problem in there. Do the following:

RotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationY (rotationY) * Matrix.CreateRotationX(rotationX) * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(rotationZ);

Comment: I'm guessing that the MathHelper.PiOver2 was to pre-align your ship to some angle.

Instead, pre-set your rotationY, X, Z to the values you want it to be initially when you start.

That should create the rotation you're looking for. With it rotating about it's center axis.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the order does matter because of the way matrices are multiplied. Matrix A times Matrix B is different than B times A. I tried that code you said to, but I got the same result. If I do `RotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationY (rotationY) * Matrix.CreateRotationX(rotationX) * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(rotationZ);` the model's Y axis rotates with it, but if I do `RotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationX (rotationX) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(rotationY) * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(rotationZ);` the X axis rotates with the ship while the Y doesn't. How do I get all the axises to rotate?

Comment: You are correct davidsbro, the order does matter. What you are experiencing is a loss in degrees of freedom due to what is known as "Gimbal Lock" as you rotate about the 3 axes. You can get around this by using quaternion operations combined together to produce the rotation you are looking for.

(Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock)
(Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up doing just in case anyone else gets stuck like I did:

```
Matrix RotationMatrix;
//every time I wanted to rotate around an axis, I would do something like this:
protected void rotateY()
    {
        RotationMatrix *= Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(RotationMatrix.Up, MathHelper.ToRadians(1.0f));
        //For the X axis I used RotationMatrix.Right, and for the Z RotationMatrix.Forward
    }
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);


    Matrix shipTransformMatrix = RotationMatrix * Matrix.CreateTranslation(ship.Position);

                    DrawModel(ship.Model, shipTransformMatrix, ship.Transforms);
    // TODO: Add your drawing code here


    base.Draw(gameTime);
}

public  void DrawModel(Model model, Matrix modelTransform, Matrix[] absoluteBoneTransforms)
{
    //Draw the model, a model can have multiple meshes, so loop
    foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
    {
        //This is where the mesh orientation is set
        foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
        {

            effect.World = absoluteBoneTransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * modelTransform;
            effect.Projection = projectionMatrix;
            effect.View = viewMatrix;

        }

        //Draw the mesh, will use the effects set above.
        mesh.Draw();
    }
}
```